# Integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\cot(1-x+x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

I don't know how to compute this integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\cot^{-1}(1-x+x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x $$

Could somebody provide me with a hint?

**Note**: $\cot^{-1}(x)$ is the $\text{arccot}$ function.

Comment: Like your previous posts, you have uploaded an image instead of a latex formula. This not pleasure for people here!

Comment: This has definitely been asked before in one way or another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint $\operatorname{arccot} (1-x+x^2)=\arctan (x)-\arctan (x-1) $ . Now use by parts separately on each function to get the answer.

Comment: Nicely done!  :D

Comment: not op, but thanks! Was just about to ask if this method was correct